# VBA excel macro 2 file handling merge error in reading

Tags: vba, excel, merge

Im trying to merge 2 Excel sheets inside a third one with the following code

```
`Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim Filepath As String
 Filepath = "C:\temp\"
 MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
  'MyFile = "12_10_15_par.xlxs"
     'If MyFile = "12_10_15_par.xlsx" Then
     If MyFile = Cells(4, 2) Then
        Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
        Worksheets("par").Range("A1:K1000").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("match").Range("T1:AF1001")
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If
     MyFile2 = Dir(Filepath)
     If MyFile2 = Cells(5, 2) Then
        Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile2)
        Worksheets("ops").Range("A1:K1000").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("match").Range("D1:S1001")
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If

 End Sub`
```

Maybe i did all wrong, because Myfile2 keeps the First value instead of getting the NEW one...

Comment: You'll need to loop to have the next value, answer is coming ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to use `Dir()`, notice at the end of the loop the `MyFile = Dir()`, it'll load the next file name in `MyFile` before looping!

Give this a try :

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MyFile As String, _
    Filepath As String, _
    oWb As Workbook, _
    pWb As Workbook

Filepath = "C:\temp\"
Set pWb = ThisWorkbook

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While MyFile <> ""
    If MyFile <> Cells(4, 2) And MyFile <> Cells(5, 2) Then
    Else
        Set oWb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)
        If MyFile <> Cells(5, 2) Then
            oWb.Worksheets("par").Range("A1:K1000").Copy Destination:=pWb.Worksheets("match").Range("T1:AF1001") '4
        Else
            oWb.Worksheets("ops").Range("A1:K1000").Copy Destination:=pWb.Worksheets("match").Range("D1:S1001") '5
        End If
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        oWb.Close
    End If
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear R3uK, thank you so much!! Not only for the answer... First thing I have to thank you for the standard procedural perspective that has to be every where (1+1 mode). So I have to open 2 workbooks (to instances as I understand),to do the job. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @NektariosKyriakou : You're welcome! Indeed I added 2 workbooks' objects to your code to reference easily those you are working this, one object for your initial workbook and one for those you'll open and then close before looping and using the same object for the other open workbook. The object variables are really practical as you can see!

Comment: @NektariosKyriakou : If you could upvote (the up arrow just on the left of the first line of the post) my answer, it would be nice as it will help me for my refiner badge!

Comment: Mkay... Doesn't seems so, because the counter is still at 0... But it's not dramatic! ;)

Comment: Ok, I guess you are looking at the value of your post, take a look on the left on the first line of my post, it's still 0 and yours is at 1! ;)